# how to convert [(String, String)] to [String, String] in Spark core with Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How to convert org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)] = org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String, String] in Spark core with Scala

```
INPUT
(2020-01-19,ERROR)
(2020-01-19,INFO)
```

```
OUTPUT
2020-01-19,ERROR
2020-01-19,INFO
```

Comment: There is not such thing as a `RDD[String, String]`. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What about using dataframes? Did you try that out?

Comment: Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples) on how to write well defined reproducible Spark questions.

Comment: Step 1: Submit pull request to have RDDs take two type parameters (doing whatever it is you want it to do, which you did not say). Step 3: Profit.

Answer (score 1):

> How to convert org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)] = org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String, String] in Spark core with Scala

You can't convert to `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String, String]`, because as you can clearly see from [the documentation of `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[T]`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD)
, it only takes one type parameter, not two. You can't convert to something that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you come from Java spark. In Scala, the equivalent of `JavaPairRDD<String, String>` is simply `RDD[(String, String)]`: In Spark Scala, `RDD[(K, V)]`s are extended with pair RDD behaviors thanks to implicit conversion (see [PairRDDFunctions](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/PairRDDFunctions.scala))